# How filter complex json on condition nested in json?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, filtering

I have an array of complex objects which I need to filter based on multiple conditions

```
var myList= [
  {
    "UserId": 1,
    "UserDetails": {
      "Department": [
        {
          "Name": "dept1"
        }
      ],
      "Projects": [
        {
          "Name": "Project1"
        },
        {
          "Name": "Project2"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "UserId": 2,
    "UserDetails": {
      "Department": [
        {
          "Name": "dept2"
        }
      ],
      "Projects": [
        {
          "Name": "Project3"
        },
        {
          "Name": "Project4"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "UserId": 3,
    "UserDetails": {
      "Department": [
        {
          "Name": "dept3"
        }
      ],
      "Projects": [
        {
          "Name": "Project5"
        },
        {
          "Name": "Project6"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

I want to filter on two conditions either Department-->Name is "dept3" or there exist a project with Name->"Project3"

```
var filteredElements=this.myList.filter((x)=>x.UserDetails.filter((y)=>y.Department... ??
```

How can I write code to filter on these two conditions?

Comment: You have a dataset and you have to filter it. What's the question? And how it has anything to do with typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To satisfy the condition

1. user belongs to a department "dept3"

   `user.UserDetails.Department.some(department => department.Name == "dept3")`
2. there is a project named "Project3"

   `user.UserDetails.Projects.some(project => project.Name == "Project3")`

Now chaining it together,

```
var filteredElements = this.myList.filter(user => 
    user.UserDetails.Department.some(department => department.Name == "dept3") || 
    user.UserDetails.Projects.some(project => project.Name == "Project3"))
```

Comment: Your code won't work. `Department` is not an object but an array. See my answer.

Comment: Edited to handle array, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
myList.filter(i => i.UserDetails.Department.some(d => d.Name === 'dept3') || i.UserDetails.Projects.some(p => p.Name === 'Project3'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the filter on `UserDetails` as it is not an array but an object.

Apply `find` on `Department` and `Projects` with OR condition between them with the required condition.

```js
var myList= [
    {
      "UserId": 1,
      "UserDetails": {
        "Department": [
          {
            "Name": "dept1"
          }
        ],
        "Projects": [
          {
            "Name": "Project1"
          },
          {
            "Name": "Project2"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "UserId": 2,
      "UserDetails": {
        "Department": [
          {
            "Name": "dept2"
          }
        ],
        "Projects": [
          {
            "Name": "Project3"
          },
          {
            "Name": "Project4"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "UserId": 3,
      "UserDetails": {
        "Department": [
          {
            "Name": "dept3"
          }
        ],
        "Projects": [
          {
            "Name": "Project5"
          },
          {
            "Name": "Project6"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
  
var filteredElements = myList.filter(x =>x.UserDetails.Department.find(d => d.Name == "dept3") || x.UserDetails.Projects.find(p => p.Name == "Project3"))
console.log(filteredElements)
```